# Why does using Go's big.Float type sometimes results in far-less precision than normal float64's ?? As in the following code:

Tags: go

The logic of the two funcs in main are identical. So, why the different and very unintuitive results?
The two functions differ only in that the second uses a more precise type throughout. So, it is the one
that ought to yield the more precise result, one would think?

```golang
//The following code's behavior is just wrong. What could explain this?

   // π = 3 + 4/(2*3*4) - 4/(4*5*6) + 4/(6*7*8) - 4/(8*9*10) + 4/(10*11*12) ...

    package main

    import (
        "fmt" 
        "math/big" 
    )

    func main(){
        with_float64_types()
        with_big_Float_types() 
    }

    // logic using float64 types: 
    func with_float64_types() {

    // float64 constants:

            var four64 float64    
                four64 = 4

            var three64 float64
                three64 = 3 

    // float64 variables:

            var digitone64 float64
                digitone64 = 2

            var digittwo64 float64
                digittwo64 = 3

            var digitthree64 float64
                digitthree64 = 4

            var sum64 float64    
                sum64 = three64 + (four64 / (digitone64*digittwo64*digitthree64)) 

            var nextterm64 float64

    // float64 proc:

            iters_fl64 := 1
        for iters_fl64 < 100000 { // 100,000
            iters_fl64++
            digitone64 = digitone64 + 2 
            digittwo64 = digittwo64 + 2
            digitthree64 = digitthree64 + 2 
            nextterm64 = four64/(digitone64*digittwo64*digitthree64)
                if iters_fl64 % 2 == 0 {  // % is modulus operator 
                    sum64 = sum64 - nextterm64 
                } else {
                    sum64 = sum64 + nextterm64
                }
        }
        fmt.Printf("\nPi via Nilakantha Somayaji per float64 types is: %0.22f \n", sum64)
        // prints 3.1415926535897864546598 which is ok
    }

    // logic using big.Float types:
    func with_big_Float_types() {

    // big.Float constants:

            twoBig := big.NewFloat(2)
            threeBig := big.NewFloat(3)
            fourBig := big.NewFloat(4)

    // big.Float variables:

            digitoneBig := new(big.Float)        
            digitoneBig = twoBig 
            digittwoBig := new(big.Float)
            digittwoBig = threeBig 
            digitthreeBig := new(big.Float)
            digitthreeBig = fourBig

            sumBig := new(big.Float) 
            nexttermBig := new(big.Float) 

        precision := 512
            sumBig.SetPrec(uint(precision))
            twoBig.SetPrec(uint(precision))
            threeBig.SetPrec(uint(precision))
            fourBig.SetPrec(uint(precision))
            digitoneBig.SetPrec(uint(precision))       
            digittwoBig.SetPrec(uint(precision))
            digitthreeBig.SetPrec(uint(precision))
            nexttermBig.SetPrec(uint(precision))

            sumBig.Add(threeBig, (new(big.Float).Quo(fourBig, new(big.Float).Mul(digitoneBig, new(big.Float).Mul(digittwoBig, digitthreeBig)))))

    // big.Float proc:

                    iterBig := 1
                for iterBig < 100000 { // 100,000
                    iterBig++

                    digitoneBig.Add(digitoneBig, twoBig)
                    digittwoBig.Add(digittwoBig, twoBig)
                    digitthreeBig.Add(digitthreeBig, twoBig)

                    nexttermBig.Quo(fourBig, new(big.Float).Mul(digitoneBig, new(big.Float).Mul(digittwoBig, digitthreeBig)))

                        if iterBig % 2 == 0 {  // % is modulus operator 
                            sumBig.Sub(sumBig, nexttermBig) 
                        } else {
                            sumBig.Add(sumBig, nexttermBig)
                        }
                }
        fmt.Printf("\nPi via Nilakantha Somayaji per big.Float types is: %0.22f \n", sumBig)
        // prints 3.1376671059697782 695252 which is very-much not ok, but why? The logic is identical. Is it not? 
}
```

Comment: Using more "precission" doesn't automatically result in faster convergence. Aside the strange way to _print_ sumBig you do the same number of iterations so your big.Float version will result in a more "accurate" result but that doesn't mean that the _convergence_ will be faster. It might be that due to rounding _errors_ in the float64 code your float64 version will yield a value nearer at pi. Using big.Float is not magic, it's still just plain numeric and you'll have to understand properties of numerical algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I located an error in my syntax. I was failing to use the asterisk operator on my variables.

the following:

```
// big.Float variables:

        digitoneBig := new(big.Float)        
        digitoneBig = twoBig 
        digittwoBig := new(big.Float)
        digittwoBig = threeBig 
        digitthreeBig := new(big.Float)
        digitthreeBig = fourBig
```

should have been:

```
// big.Float variables:

        digitoneBig := new(big.Float)        
        *digitoneBig = *twoBig 
        digittwoBig := new(big.Float)
        *digittwoBig = *threeBig 
        digitthreeBig := new(big.Float)
        *digitthreeBig = *fourBig
```